# Java open cmd and execute command using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make an ide just for fun I have no idea why but i wan't to open cmd and execute 2 commands 1 for compiling and 1 for running the compiled file.

This is how my processbuilder looks like:

```
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "/k", "javac", "EkkoFunIde.java", "java", "EkkoFunIde.class");
```

But nothing happens no excepetions are thrown but when i only have this:

```
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start");
```

It does open cmd.

I write to the file like this:

```
ObservableList<CharSequence> paragraph = area.getParagraphs();
        Iterator<CharSequence>  iter = paragraph.iterator();
        try {
            BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                CharSequence seq = iter.next();
                bf.append(seq);
                bf.newLine();
            }
            bf.flush();
            bf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And after the process has started i delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to call `start` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start--) (example at the top of article about ProcessBuilder class):

```
...
process.start();
```

Comment: Nope i didn't forget that I just didn't post it here